# Using Node.js API on my react-native frontend

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am new to react-native. I am using an api that basically returns json data, I am able to easily use json on my frontend but I am stuck because I don't know how to redirect to my other frontend file using same api but different route.

Comment: could you please be more clear. you should explain what is your goal, what you've tried and what the result was?

Comment: generally I would say look into Express.js and watch some youtubevideos on how to connect React Native and with an ExpressJS backend because I also learned it that way and it helped me a LOT! Hitting a different route is like in the web you need to set up your ExpressJS server in a way that you have specific routes with routenames that target something different.